# Using randomForest package in R, how to map Random forest prediction?

Tags: r, random, prediction

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zR0vI.png)I am trying to use randomforest to generate a spatial prediction map.

I developed my model by using random forest regression, but I met a little difficulty in the last step to use the best predictors for building the predictive map. I want to create a map prediction map.

### My code:

```
library(raster)
library(randomForest)

set.seed(12)
s <- stack("Density.tif", "Aqui.tif", "Rech.tif", "Rainfall.tif","Land Use.tif", "Cond.tif", "Nitrogen.tif", "Regions.tif","Soil.tif","Topo.tif", "Climatclass.tif", "Depth.tif")

points <- read.table("Coordonnées3.txt",header=TRUE, sep="\t", dec=",",strip.white=TRUE)

d <- extract(s, points)
rf <-randomForest(nitrate~ . , data=d, importance=TRUE, ntree=500, na.action = na.roughfix)
p <- predict(s, rf)

plot(p)
```

### Sample Data:

```
> head(points)
       LAT      LONG
1 -13.057007 27.549580
2  -4.255000 15.233745
3   5.300000 -1.983610
4   7.245675 -4.233336
5  12.096330 15.036016
6  -4.255000 15.233745
```

The error when I run my short code is:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'nitrate' not found.
```

Comment: `head(d)` will help to debug your question better plus look into `d` if it have nitrate or Nitrogen as column name.

Comment: Which line of code generates the error? Is it the model fitting or the prediction?

Comment: The error of code appear when I run in the step: rf <-randomForest(nitrate~ . , data=d, importance=TRUE, ntree=500, na.action = na.roughfix)

Comment: I have twelve predictors in raster format. The diffrents rasters are stocked in : s <- stack("Density.tif", "Aqui.tif", "Rech.tif", "Rainfall.tif",
           "Land Use.tif", "Cond.tif", "Nitrogen.tif", "Regions.tif", "Soil.tif",
           "Topo.tif", "Climat class.tif", "Depth.tif"). My objective is to use the nitrate (logtransformed of nitrate) as  response variable   to create the prediction map.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing the error happens when you fit the model.

Why would there be a variable called `nitrate`. Given how you create your RasterStack, perhaps there is one called `Nitrogen`. Either way you can find out by looking at `names(s)` and `colnames(d)`.

NOTE that your `points` are not good! They are in reverse order. The order should be (longitude, latitude).

Based on your comments (please edit your question instead), you should 
add nitrate the points file (the third column) or something like that. Then do

```
 xy <- points[, 2:1]
 nitrate <- points[,3]
```

Extract points and combine with your observed data

```
 d <- extract(s, xy)
 d <- cbind(nitrate=nitrate, d)
```

Build model and predict

```
 rf <-randomForest(nitrate~ . , data=d, importance=TRUE, ntree=500, na.action = na.roughfix)
 p <- predict(s, rf)
```

Comment: I have twelve predictors in raster format. The diffrents rasters are stocked in : s <- stack("Density.tif", "Aqui.tif", "Rech.tif", "Rainfall.tif",
           "Land Use.tif", "Cond.tif", "Nitrogen.tif", "Regions.tif", "Soil.tif",
           "Topo.tif", "Climat class.tif", "Depth.tif").

Comment: If I add the nitrate value to "points", I obtain:

 head(points)
  Ln.NO3._mean        LAT      LONG
1    0.2311117 -13.057007 27.549580
2    0.3148107  -4.255000 15.233745
3    0.3162695   5.300000 -1.983610
4    0.4054651   7.245675 -4.233336
5    0.4054651  12.096330 15.036016
6    0.6205765  -4.255000 15.233745

In this case, if I put the nitrate values with LAT and LONG, when I run again, the error appear is: 
> d <- extract(s, points)
Error in .xyValues(x, as.matrix(y), ...) : xy should have 2 columns only.
Found these dimensions: 82, 3

Comment: The variable called nitrate isn't in raster format. But a quantitative variable.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the error is coming when you are trying to build the forest. It may be most helpful to not use the formula interface. Also, if `d` is large, then using the formula interface is not advisable. From the help file on `randomForest`: "For large data sets, especially those with large number of variables, calling randomForest via the formula interface is not advised: There may be too much overhead in handling the formula."

Assuming `d$nitrate` exists then the solution is `randomForest(y = d$nitrate, x = subset(d, select = -nitrate), importance=TRUE, ntree=500, na.action = na.roughfix)`